# Why am I required to install Oracle JRE while installing TFS?

Tags: windows-10, installation, java, team-foundation-server

I'm installing a new TFS instance and, as suggested by [the docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/install/single-server?view=tfs-2018), I installed the SQL Server (on the same machine, which is brand new and freshly blown).

During the installation process, I got the error message that *Oracle Server JRE* is required. That surprised me. A lot. Googling gave more suggestions on how to make it work than shed light over why it needs to be done.

I'm running MS operative system, installing MS application powered by MS database executed in the domain of MS cloud which then will manage version control and builds of MS framework based software.

Can someone explain why, oh why, I need to install anything from Oracle/Java at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to install Java because TFS Code Search uses ElasticSearch, which runs on Java.

Reference: from [Code & Work Item Search for TFS 2017 – Troubleshooting](https://intovsts.net/2017/11/12/code-work-item-search-for-tfs-2017-troubleshooting/):

> For TFS 2017 on-premises, Code Search includes Elasticsearch and will be configured on a server running TFS 2017